# Splitting a DataFrame into an Array Using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a file called data that looks like this:

```
Some Text Information (lines 1-6 in file)
1 22 23
2 44 44
3 55 55
4 66 66
5 77 77
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this something like this:

```
 [[ 22.  23.]
 [ 44.    44.]
 [ 55.  55.]
 [  66.   66.]
 [ 77.  77.]]
```

The issue I'm having is that the code I'm using doesn't properly split the data from the file. It ends up looking like this:

```
 [   1 22 23
0    2 44 44
1  3 55 55, Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1 6734 1453]
Index: [],      1 22 23
2      4 44 44
3    5   55 55
4    6 66 66
5    7 77 77
   EOF]
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
def loadFile(filename):
    df1 = pd.read_fwf(filename, skiprows=6)
    df1 = np.split(df, [2,2])
    print('The data points:\n {}'.format(df1[:5]))
```

I understand the parameters of the split function. For instance, [2,2] should create two sub arrays from my dataframe and my axis is 0. However, why does it not properly split the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read file into `pandas` dataFrame and access the `values` attribute from it. Assuming "Some Text Information" is not the `header`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(filepath, sep='\t', index_col= 0, skiprows = 6, header = None)

df.values                      # gives you the numpy ndarray
```

This should use the *first column* as `index`. Also you might need to remove the `sep` argument to let *read_table* figure it out. Also, try using other separators. If you get the row index in your data then try slicing to get desired results. Use something like:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].values
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I get a  parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skiprow' error when running that.

Comment: sorry its `skiprows`. corrected it. Also, most probably  your separator is tab, but if it doesn't work then remove the `sep` argument and try again.

Comment: That's alright. So, that works. However, I still have the first column value showing. To expand, it looks like this: `[2 2233 10, 3 5530 1424, 4 401 841, 5 3082 1644, 6 7608 4458]` When it should look like this: `[ 2233 10, 5530 1424,401 841,3082 1644, 7608 4458]`

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this error: `cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [1] of <class 'int'>`

Comment: Use `df.iloc[:,1:].values`

Comment: The output is still: `Index: [2 22 22, 3 33 33, 4 44 44, 5 55 55, 6 66 66]` The file isn't in any particular format.So, it's just spaces. I'm not sure if it recognizes the first space as column 1?

Comment: i modified above code a bit. try again. why is this all information in your above comment starts as Index:  ... ??:

Comment: I figured it out. I separated through ' ' and used William's answer as well. So, my df is `df = pd.read_table(filename,sep=' ', index_col= 0, skiprows = 6).iloc[:, 1:]`

However, I needed to change my .iloc column position to 0 because the line number needs to be omitted. The df.values command got me the arrays and I was able to reshape them from there. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nice it worked out. Its all about hit and trial sometimes. Try posting the dummy data in your file format or a part of your file next time to let others help better.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `read_fwf`, let pandas figure out the structure of your table:

```
df = pd.read_csv("yourfile", skiprows=6, header=None, sep='\s+')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip- I made the adjustment. However, it still doesn't split it into what I was looking for :/

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on ManKind_008's answer:

Your explicit line numbers are the problem. Pandas interprets these as valid data.
Using ManKinds solution does properly set the index column, but since your line numbers start at zero you end up with a DataFrame like:

```
pd.read_fwf('test.csv', header=None, index_col=0, skiprows=6)
    1   2
0        
1  22  23
2  44  44
3  55  55
4  66  66
5  77  77
```

Instead I suggest you read in all of your data using:

```
pd.read_fwf('test.csv', header=None, skiprows=6).iloc[:, 1:]
    1   2
0  22  23
1  44  44
2  55  55
3  66  66
4  77  77
```

This leaves you with what you seem to need. The `iloc` call is ignoring the first row of data (your line numbers).

From here the `df.values` command will give you:

```
array([[22, 23],
   [44, 44],
   [55, 55],
   [66, 66],
   [77, 77]])
```

If you don't want a np.array, you can explicitly cast this to a list using the `list()` function.

Comment: Running the above gives me this: `The data points:
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[]`

Did I miss a step?